# Arduino Only Reads only one character.

Tags: c++, arduino

This program is meant to read an input, and write it out in the Arduino's serial monitor. The issue that it only write one character in the serial monitor.

```
void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600); //Set the serial monitor.
lcd.begin(16, 2); //Set the LCD
}
// Alignment variables
boolean left = true; //Set boolean left to true to begin to display text in middle of screen.
boolean right = false; //Other possible align booleans set to false
boolean select = false;
//Text show/hide variables
boolean show1 = true;  //Both values set to true to display on start up.
boolean show2 = true;
//Serial input
char serialinput [4] = {0}; //For 3 value input, and null character to end.
char line1;
void loop()
 {

 if (Serial.available() > 0) { //If the serial monitor is open it will read a value.
    line1 = Serial.read();
    Serial.print(line1);
    memmove (serialinput, &serialinput[1], 3); //copy the value to memory
    serialinput [2] = Serial.read(); //value is read.
    //if statements for each possible input.

}
```

Comment: Since `line1` is a single `char`, how do you expect it to process more than one character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serial.read doesn't wait for the end of a string.  If you're trying to read a few characters (implied by [4]) you only need to include a short delay() after serial.read to allow enough time for the buffer to completely dump the string.

```
if (Serial.available() > 0) { //If the serial monitor is open it will read a value.
 line1 = Serial.read();
 delay(100);
 Serial.print(line1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You read one byte to line1, then you print that byte. A line should be printed in a loop or such. Also this comment:

```
if (Serial.available() > 0) { 
//If the serial monitor is open it will read a value.
```

is not really true. `Serial.available()` returns the number of bytes that are currently in the buffer. Thus this line: `serialinput[2] = Serial.read();` is calling `read()` wihtout  verifying that there is anything to be read. Apparently there are `//if statements for each possible input.` at the end of the `loop()`, what do these do? I suspect there is no logic to assert where in `serialinput[]` a particular byte will end up. Sending a message that is longer than 2 bytes to your code as it is posted here will overwrite the values.